# Naming convention for a method that create a new object from the current instance but modifies some properties

Tags: javascript, immutability, naming

I was wondering if there are any common conventions for a **method** that:

1. returns a new instance of the same type of object;
2. using the current instance's property values as the defaults;
3. while changing at least one of the property values.

---

## Example

E.g. If this method were called `foo` on a class `Node`, then:

```
class MyNode {

  constructor({aKey, bKey}) {
    this.aKey = aKey ?? 0
    this.bKey = bKey ?? 0
  }

  /* The method I'm not sure how to name: */
  foo({aKey, bKey}) {
    return new MyNode({
      aKey: aKey ?? this.aKey, // use this instance's value as a fallback.
      bKey: bKey ?? this.bKey
    })
  }

}

const nodeA = new Node({aKey: 1}); 
console.log(nodeA) 
// {aKey: 1, bKey: 0}

const nodeB = nodeA.foo({bKey: 1});
console.log(nodeB);
// {aKey: 1, bKey: 1}
```

---

Alternatively, if anyone has a suggestion for a better way to avoid mutating the objects while using existing instances to create new instances, I'd be equally interested in alternative approaches.

Comment: I doubt there's a generic convention for this. The name should reflect the relationship between the old and new object. For instance, if you have an integer class and a method that returns the number times 2, you might call it `doubled()`.

Comment: It's basically just cloning. The potential override of a property is perhaps not quite usual but also does not really stray from the cloning part.

Comment: @VLAZ It is rather common in functional programming with immutable data structures

Comment: Could anyone who voted to close this question based on it being "opinion-based" please provide some feedback as to how to adjust it? The "opinion-based" tag says: "_This question is likely to be answered with **opinions rather than facts and citations**. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers._"; however, the actual answer is replete with citations. Similarly, I'd appreciate feedback from those who down-voted -- I tried my best to make a clear, concise question and spent a nontrivial amount of time looking through existing questions for applicable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such [fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) often use [`with` as a method name prefix](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/430066/66652). This convention is explicitly [documented for the Java Date-Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html), but can be found in many APIs. It might be related to languages that use `with` as a keyword in their syntax for record updates (e.g. [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation), [OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/records.html)), though there's also many languages with immutable record types that don't use a keyword in their syntax (e.g. [Haskell](https://devtut.github.io/haskell/record-syntax.html#copying-records-while-changing-field-values), [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/docs/records#updating-records), [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax)).

The convention is also used in JavaScript, see e.g. the native [`Array.prototype.with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/with) method or the [`with`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/zoneddatetime.html#with) and [`with…`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/zoneddatetime.html#withPlainTime) methods in classes of the upcoming Temporal proposal. For your case, it would typically be `Node().withAkey(1).withBkey(1)` or `Node().with({aKey: 1, bKey: 1})`.

Comment: Yes, every method call returns a new object; but you can have both methods that set only a single property and a method that sets multiple properties at once. I'm not aware of a name for this pattern - related are the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and "(functional) record update" syntax.

Comment: does the fact that the question has been closed affect you in any way (e.g. rep points)? I don't understand why it's been closed and the steps for requesting that it be reopened just say to "call for the question to be reopened in the comments", which I did. It now says it wasn't reopened and the only option is to edit, but there's no information (that I can see) about what would need to be edited. **If there's anything I can do to ensure your effort wasn't wasted, let me know**; I'm happy just having a clear answer. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @RaxAdaam Thanks, I'm fine (and I do get rep from the votes and accept, though I don't care any longer). There's two reopen votes already, there's nothing more you need to do. (If you wanted, you could edit the question to get it more views, or mention it in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org)).